# Display unchecked records from an Access database in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am creating a VB.NET application that is supposed to work with my Access database. I have created and imported a Microsoft Access 2010 database (.accdb) into VB.NET and made one of the tables to display on my form. On form 1 I have a button which links to form 2, on which the database table is displayed.

What I want to do is generate some kind of `IF` statement to say if a particular field in a record is unchecked than display it in a list-box on FORM 1.

For example I have a filed called "started" and its data type is `Yes/No`. When a particular record is not checked (empty check-box) I want it to display in a list box on form 1.

Could someone advise me if this is possible and how I could go around doing this?

EDIT: After trying a few things out, here is what I have so far. The table 'Jobs' is being highlighted as not declared *('Jobs' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.)* and I can't figure out how to do this, as the database is connected.

```
 Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstTostart.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Started, SQLString As String
    Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source = KNmidlands_db.accdb"
    SQLString = "SELECT *  FROM Jobs WHERE Started = 0"  '--> 1 = Yes / 0 = No
    If Jobs.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        For x As Integer = 0 To Jobs.Rows.Count - 1

            lstTostart.Items.Add(Jobs.Rows(x).Item("whatever"))

        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks
Aleksander

Comment: So are these VB.NET forms you're talking about?

Comment: Gord Thompson, Yes VB.NET forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Me.OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(Me.DataSet11.Jobs)
    Fill_List()
End Sub

Sub Fill_List()
    Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = kn.accdb"
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(ConnectString)
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    con.Open()
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT *  FROM Jobs WHERE NOT Started = true", con)
    da.Fill(dt)

    MsgBox(Format(dt.Rows.Count))

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        For x As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            ListBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(x).Item("Job ID"))

        Next

    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I have a list box in which I want to show particular records from my database. I want it to show the ID/name of the record that has an empty check box in the field started. So it checks the database table JOBS looks for all records that have the field Started as no (or empty) and display them in the list box (using the name or ID of the record).

Comment: There is no errors, but the list displays an empty item (one rectangle with dotted border and white space inside). I have made a fresh project, with new database and a database connection. I have added the oledbDataAdapter and created a dataSet and added a listbox with the code.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work too. If you don't mind would you be able to test in on a test project, on your computer and see what's wrong with it? - if you have time though.

Comment: Ok, this is the test project I have been working on: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/109348302/testKN.zip

Comment: @user1588549 : just try it .. you can improve this